# Time Complexity while using library functions

Tags: time-complexity

If within a for loop (running say n times ),i make a call to a library function,which i know in the back end runs another loop,does it affect my overall complexity ? Or does it remain O(n) ?

Comment: It depends on whether the library function's complexity depends on `n`. If it's, say, a sort routine, then yes; if it's a square root routine, then probably not.

Comment: 1)  If you took the code from the library with the loop and C&P'd it into your function, so that instead of calling the library it runs the same code, would that increase your complexity?  2) What is the difference in those two cases?

Answer (score 0):

It does affect your overall complexity. Imagine you were to make a call to the function you're writing from within another loop - you can't ignore a function's inherent runtime because it looks like a single statement.

Now, exactly HOW it affects your complexity depends on what you're doing with it, and what it does, but you certainly can't ignore it.

Comment: For instance lets say i'm making a call to the pow function n times , in this case how do you think the complexity will work out?

Comment: in this case, complexity of your fuction = n(outer for loop)* complexityOfPowerFunction * n(no of times poweer function is called)